# Qt Creator + git checkout + full recompile

Tags: c++, git, qt, compilation, qt-creator

Is there a way to avoid full recompile after you checkout a branch, do some editing, then checkout the branch you were on previously?

It looks like build system detects that files have been swapped around and demands full recompilation despite the fact that those are the same files that you compiled previously. Any way to avoid that?

UPD: I should probably point out that I am using Visual C++ compiler.

Comment: Give a try to CMake.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have the `Project.pro.user` file in *git* repo?

Comment: no. it's in .gitignore

Comment: Are you using a shadow build?

Comment: Yhen the whole thing is interesting. I wonder what triggers the full rebuild then, if it is not changes in project settings (that .pro.user file). *make* shouldn't care, as long as time stamps are valid...

Comment: @mitch, yes, I do use it.

Comment: @hyde qt creator detects that files change and seems to rerun qmake on them the moment you switch branches. I suspect that triggers it

Comment: @hyde, I suspect that time stamps change for the newly checked out files

Comment: Well, as a workaround, I would suggest just getting a 2nd clone of the repo,, and doing the edits to the other branch there.

Comment: That's what I am doing at the moment, but this is annoying

Answer (score 2):

You did not specificy what kind of branch you are checking out. In case you are checking out one vastly different compared to your initial one, e.g. master vs gh-pages on Github, the timestamps on the source files will be newer than the corresponding binary files. In that case, the following should help:

1) If you are using a GNU make based build system, execute `make -t`. This marks all targets as up-to-date by setting their [modification timestamps to the current time.](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Instead-of-Execution)

2) [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org/) can decrease the recompile time of exactly the same source code by magnitudes. At least on Linux it is also extremely easy to [set up and use](http://dragly.org/2013/05/13/speeding-up-compilation-on-ubuntu-with-qt-creator/).